# Run-Time error '32809': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

All,

I just upgraded to **Excel 2013** and am running into a strange issue. I have a macro-enabled workbook that has worked successfully for quite some time now. I was updating some of the code and came across this **error (32809)** when trying to write to a specific sheet. In troubleshooting, I tried this.

**`Sheets("Summary").Range("G8").Value = "Test"`**

This resulted in the same error. Then I tried this.

**`Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name`**

Same error. So I selected another sheet on the workbook and debug.print on the name. Worked fine.

Then I tried this.

**`Debug.Print Sheets(2).Name`** (This is the sheet number of the problemic sheet)

Same error. It seems to me that there is some form of corruption with this sheet but I am reticent about deleting and recreating. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi & welcome Greg. If you access the sheet by its name (the name you expect to see printed), instead of Sheets(2), what happens?

Comment: oh I see, the name is supposed to be "Summary", but it seems corrupted somehow.

Comment: Before you rewrite the workbook, reboot your machine and try again. A VBA environment can become unstable after a number of programming crashes.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I did try referencing by the actual name and had the same issue. I will reboot my machine when I return to work and see if that resolves it. Thanks!

Comment: I've had 'xl13 error just by opening the darn thing. I have stuck with xl'10, it seems more stable.

Comment: It looks like an XML error in the header. What happens if you copy the sheet to a new workbook? Maybe the initialization helps fixing the header. If so, you can copy it back again.

Comment: Or you can copy all cells to a new sheet that replaces the original.

Comment: Check your references (in Tools > References) to see if any are marked as "MISSING:" Any missing references tend to cause very weird errors

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to some corrupt ActiveX controls on the sheet. I can copy the sheet and delete the ActiveX controls without issue, but when I try to delete the controls on the original sheet, it crashes Excel. Also, if I try to delete the sheet it will crash Excel. Any ideas on how to get rid of this sheet?

Comment: Can you move the original sheet to a new workbook?

Answer (score 2):

While it wasn't a perfect solution, here is how I finally resolved it. I had a user that was still on Excel 2010 make a copy the corrupt sheet within the same workbook, delete the corrupt sheet, then rename the new sheet to the original name. I was then able to use the workbook in Excel 2013 without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Workbook Open Macro which counts the number of rows in a table on opening so that I can summarize how many records were added or deleted during the data entry session:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim TotalRows As Integer
    TotalRows = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count
    If Range("LastRecordOnStart") <> TotalRows Then Range("LastRecordOnStart") = TotalRows
'    Stop
End Sub
```

I started getting the run-time error '32809' with the following line in the code above highlighted in the debugger every time I opened the workbook...

```
TotalRows = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count
```

Rebooting or opening the workbook on another PC still would not fix it.  Even opening a previously saved working copy would give the same error - strange.  Note:

While coding, I will periodically save the workbook and use windows explorer to copy a snapshot of the workbook where it creates myworkbook copy(1).xlsm, copy(2).xlsm, etc and if I get a corrupted workbook, I rename it myworkbook.bad.xlsm and rename the latest saved working version (e.g myworkbook copy(6).xlsm to MyWorkbook.xlsm with minimal loss.

When this run-time error occurs though, I've had to rebuild the book several times.  It only appears to happen when the workbook crashes after a long session of debugging new code with the Userform open and I have to close excel from the Task Manager.

I read the posts here today and was convinced that it was page related when I could list the listrows count on another sheet and if I converted the Listobject on the "Data" worksheet back to a range and recreated the table, I'd still get the run-time error.  To cut a long story short, I tried the following:

1. Open the workbook
2. When the error popped up, clicked debug
3. Right clicked on the "End Sub" line of the WorkBook_Open sub and clicked "Set Next statement"
4. Pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> to allow the code to finish executing
5. Saved the workbook and it all works now!

I had another crash with the subsequent run-time error and repeated the steps above and it worked a charm again.